# Interpolating big data values with SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, interpolation

I am fairly new to SQL and big data in general so bear with me here. I have a table of values for a year's worth of weather data. I am looking at temperature and precipitation for every hour of the day (thus around 9000 values), but the problem is that the weather station only recorded precipitation every 6 hours. So, I want to interpolate the time points and obtain values but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's a snippet of the table:

`Year   Month   Day    Hour   Temperature  Precipitation
2014    1         1       0      -16.5444              0
2014    1         1       1      -10.3455          *****
2014    1         1       2      -5.34855          *****
2014    1         1       3      -15.4569          *****
2014    1         1       4      -4.45666          *****
2014    1         1       5      -11.2344          *****
2014    1         1       6      -13.3454              0
2014    1         1       7      -20.2334          *****
2014    1         1       8      -2.48555          *****
2014    1         1       9      -5.43554          *****
2014    1         1      10      -1.34555          *****
2014    1         1      11      -9.00333          *****
2014    1         1      12      -6.43555           0.04
2014    1         1      13      -12.3423          *****
2014    1         1      14      -8.56664          *****
2014    1         1      15      -15.3498          *****
2014    1         1      16      -19.2384          *****
2014    1         1      17      -21.2348          *****
2014    1         1      18      -23.8778           0.31
2014    1         1      19      -20.8374          *****
2014    1         1      20      -25.3874          *****
2014    1         1      21      -21.3445          *****
2014    1         1      22      -27.4599          *****
2014    1         1      23      -30.9384          *****
2014    1         2       0      -25.9085           0.15`

Comment: Did you have a chance to try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a fast way of doing this but I do see a way.

Here are the things you will need :

2 new tables, 2 procedures to fill the tables and 1 procedure to interpolate in your actual table.

Follow these 3 steps :

1 : In the first procedure you want to go through your weather table and collect all the precipitations (only the ones every 6 hours not the ***** ones) and insert them in your first table

2 : In the second procedure you want to fill the second table of your interpolation values. Here you will have to do some maths to figure out what numbers will be inserted

3 : In the last procedure you want to go through your Weather table and replace every ***** value by its corresponding number in the 2nd table (filled up in step 2).

To do this you will need to use a CURSOR in your procedures. Once your interpolation is done you can delete the 2 tables created in step 1 and 2.

I hope this is clear enough. There might be a simpler way but not that I know of. If anything is unclear ask for precision in comments and I will edit my answer.

Comment: If you do not have access to Procedures but have access to PHP you can use lists or arrays instead of tables in Step 1 and 2 @paulkariya

Comment: This may in fact work, but it doesn't solve my problem of calculating thousands of interpolated values. There must be another way..

Comment: I think it does in the case of a linear interpolation. Lets say you need to calculate the values of precipations 13 to 17. In the first step you collected the values of precipitation 12 and 18 which are 0,04 and 0,31. If you do 0,31 - 0,04 you obtain 0,27 which you then divide by 6 (getting the 5 precipitations in between) and you get 0,045. Therefor precipitation 13 is 0.04 + 0,045 = 0,085.  These calculations can easily be done in your loops after thinking on it for a while @paulkariya

Comment: Values such as 0,085 mentionned in previous comment represent the values needed in step 2

Comment: Also I mentionned PHP earlier as it is mainly what I have seen Sqlite being used in but it can be done in any other programming language

Answer (score 0):

If the output you want is:

```
Year        Month       Day         hour        Precipitation_interpolated
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  --------------------------
2014        1           1           0           0.0
2014        1           1           1           0.0
2014        1           1           2           0.0
2014        1           1           3           0.0
2014        1           1           4           0.0
2014        1           1           5           0.0
2014        1           1           6           0.0
2014        1           1           7           0.00666666666666667
2014        1           1           8           0.0133333333333333
2014        1           1           9           0.02
2014        1           1           10          0.0266666666666667
2014        1           1           11          0.0333333333333333
2014        1           1           12          0.04
2014        1           1           13          0.085
2014        1           1           14          0.13
2014        1           1           15          0.175
2014        1           1           16          0.22
2014        1           1           17          0.265
2014        1           1           18          0.31
2014        1           1           19          0.283333333333333
2014        1           1           20          0.256666666666667
2014        1           1           21          0.23
2014        1           1           22          0.203333333333333
2014        1           1           23          0.176666666666667
2014        1           2           0           0.15
```

Then the query below will produce that. It might not be very efficient due to depending on a lot of subqueries for row numbering/partitioning (which SQLite doesn't have native support for) and it uses common table expressions which was added in version 3.8.3 (released on 2014-02-03; if you're using an older version you need to upgrade or rewrite the query to not use common table expressions - it should be possible but I didn't try).

The query uses a table `t` as source; it's only referenced in the from clause of the very first select statement and also I assumed that the `*****` in your sample data were placeholders for `null` values:

```
with src as (
    select year, month, day, hour, precipitation, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', year ||'-'|| case when length(month) = 1 then 0||month else month end || '-' ||case when length(day) = 1 then 0||day else day end || case when length(hour) = 1 then 0||hour else hour end ||':00:00') as dt from t
), sample_data as (
        select year, month, day, hour, dt, Precipitation, (select count(*) from src b where a.dt >= dt) as id from src a 
), value_rows as (
    select id, Precipitation,
    (select count(*) from src b where val.dt >= dt and Precipitation is not null ) rn
    from (
        select id, Precipitation, dt
        from sample_data
        where Precipitation is not null
    ) val
), step_change as (
    select c1.id id_Start
        , c2.id - 1 id_End
        , c1.Precipitation
        , (c2.Precipitation - c1.Precipitation)/(c2.id - c1.id) change
    From value_rows c1
    inner join value_rows c2
    on c1.rn = c2.rn - 1
), interpolated_values as (
    select s.id
        , s.Year
        , s.Month
        , s.Day
        , s.Hour
        , s.Precipitation as value1
        , coalesce(sc.Precipitation, s.Precipitation) Precipitation
        , coalesce(sc.change, 0) change
        , coalesce((select count(*) from src b where s.dt >= dt) - id_Start, 0) coeff
        , sc.id_Start ,sc.id_End
    from sample_data s
    left outer join step_change sc
    on s.id between sc.id_Start and sc.id_End
) 

select Year, Month, Day, hour, Precipitation + coeff * change Precipitation_interpolated
from interpolated_values
order by id;
```

I patched together the SQLite version from a t-sql query found on the SQL Server MSDN forum ([here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a740d2f5-bd36-47cd-b448-df0fe84300ef/linear-interpolate)).